# Unity abrir link externo

Tags: aplicação-web, unity3d

Ao colocar o ficheiro de unity na página não consigo rederecionar a ação para outra página. O que acontece é que a nova página é aberta dentro do "frame" destinado ao ficheiro unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Urlazerecovelo : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        Application.OpenURL("https://www.google.pt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sua pergunta não está bem clara, mas pelo que eu entendi você fez um projeto na Unity3D, compilou pra web (isto é, gerou a versão em WebGL), colocou-a pra rodar em uma página sua, e aí testou o seu código.

Bom, nesse caso, o seu código não vai mesmo funcionar como você espera. Segundo a documentação de [`Application.OpenURL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html), ele abre a URL no navegador padrão, mas o resultado não é especificado caso a aplicação esteja rodando no navegador. Ainda assim, eu acho condizente ele abrir no mesmo frame em que a aplicação está rodando.

Se você quer mais controle e fazer interações externas (com JavaScript, por exemplo), use o método [`Application.ExternalEval`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.ExternalEval.html). Teste o seu código assim, por exemplo:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Urlazerecovelo: MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Application.ExternalEval("window.open(\"https://www.google.pt\")");
    }
}
```

Ainda assim, interações entre a sua aplicação e o JavaScript deveriam ser limitadas ou reduzidas ao mínimo. Se vc está tendo um esforço de construir uma aplicação na Unity, procure fazer as interações mais importantes nela mesmo, pois só assim você consegue a portabilidade (isto é, rodar em outras plataformas) que é justamente um dos fortes dessa ferramenta.